# Probability of selecting a biased coin?

Tags: probability, dice

Me and a few classmates were working through a probability & statistics past paper:

> We have two coins denoted H1 and H2. Coin H1 is fair, i.e. $P(h) = P(t)$
>   $= 1/2$, $h$ being head and $t$ being tail. Coin H2 is loaded with $P(h) = 3/5$. We pick one of the coins at random, toss it and head shows. What
>   is the probability that we picked the loaded coin?

The answers says that it is $\frac{6}{11}$, but we have no clue how they got to this answer....

Answer (score 2):

Hint : You have to use Bayes theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{P(H2\land h)}{P(H2\land h)+P(H1\land h)} =\frac{\frac12\frac35}{\frac12\frac35+\frac12\frac12}$$